# SmartGWT modal window

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have problem with modal window. I call this two methods `setIsModal(true)` and `setShowModalMask(true)` but why my window isn't modal ?

Here is the Code :

```
Window summaryWindow = new Window();
summaryWindow.setWidth(950);
summaryWindow.setHeight(620);
summaryWindow.centerInPage();
summaryWindow.setCanDragReposition(false);
summaryWindow.setIsModal(true);
summaryWindow.setShowModalMask(true);
summaryWindow.setShowMinimizeButton(false);
summaryWindow.setTitle("Example");
summaryWindow.addItem(new Button("Example");
summaryWindow.show();
```

Comment: check this out http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/ModalwindowwithcontrolsSmartGWT.htm

Comment: as @Parvathy said ..show the code also .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you're getting is valid. In any GWT related technology, you'll find many API functionalities to set properties of GWT widget. For example, for a `Window` widget you have, `setWidth`, `setHeight`, `centerInPage` etc...

Now some of these properties MUST be applied before the widget is rendered in DOM of the browser & some of them MUST be applied after the widget is rendered in DOM of the browser.

`ShowModalMask()` is a property that you can set only before the widget is rendered.
`centerInPage()` is a property that renders Window in DOM of browser & that is the reason you're getting the exception.

Apply properties in a proper order (`centerInPage()` after `ShowModalMask()` in your case) to avoid this kind of exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using smartgwt 2.4 : if I try your code with a button calling it enclosed in a method I get an error which indicated I cannot modify it with setModalMask (`IllegalStateException - this property cannot be changed after the component has been created`) . 
After moving this call just after the instanciation it's working:

```
Window summaryWindow = new Window();
summaryWindow.setShowModalMask(true);
```

I don't really understand, but let me know if it's also working for you